# tempdata not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

Form.php(controller)

```
public function dispdata()
{
        $result['data']=$this->Form_model->displayrecords();
        $this->load->view('display_records',$result);

        if (!$this->session->userdata('ci_session')) 
        {
            redirect('Form/login');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_tempdata('item',$result,5);
        }
}
```

display_records(view)

```
<?php 
        if($this->session->tempdata('item')){
            redirect('Form/login');
        }
?>
```

im trying to work with the tempdata concept. i have a registration form where i have stored all the registered details in the datbase and those store details of database i have displayed 
it in the view page.

how that i have displayed all the database details in a view page that view page im trying to display only for 5sec and after 5sec it should redirect to the login page. i have tried with the above code but its not working please can anyone tel me where im going wrong ?

Comment: you can use jqery settimeout function for that

Comment: once you redirect to view page you can use jquery timeout function to redirect to login page.

Answer (score 0):

As per `codeigniter` documents `session` display as per below..

```
$_SESSION['item'] = 'value';
$this->session->mark_as_temp('item', 300); // Expire in 5 minutes
```

or

```
$this->session->set_tempdata('item', base_url('controller/method'), 300);
```

Comment: this one i know sir but how to execute this concept in my project i have tried alot but unable to do please can u guide me

Comment: Hello dear , please. look editable answer.i think,this solution is better the before